# Entered integer was not taken as a numeric in rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

There is a strange error in our rails 3.1.0 app when saving a new quote in quotes controller. A quote belongs to a rfq and rfq is 18 was passed into the quotes controller. The error is:

```
Validation failed: Quoted total is not a number
```

The parameters displayed are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"p9waUq7wNk6djm9uRtDOA0eHLzzlJuSCWrTsSEBvcck=",
 "quote"=>{"test_item_ids"=>["1",
 "2"],
 "_destroy"=>"false",
 "quoted_total"=>"290"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "rfq_id"=>"18"}
```

As it shows, the quoted_total is 290. But somehow it was not recognized as a number.

Here is the create code in quotes controller:

```
    @quote = @rfq.quotes.new(params[:quote], :as => :roles_new)
    @quote.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
    @quote.test_items =  TestItem.find_all_by_id(params[:quote][:test_item_ids]) 
    if @quote.save!
      redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=quote saved!")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not saved!"
      render 'new'
    end
```

The error is caused by @quote.save. The rspec code for the quote controller has the same error. What caused the error? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you validate quoted_total as a number in your model, in fact, the params[:quoted_total] is a string.

Comment: yes, as: validates_numericality_of :quoted_total, :greater_than => 0.00. But all data returned by params are all strings and the model knows how to convert them.

Comment: Found the problem! it is caused by the wrong name in attr_accessible. quoted_total is not in attr_accessible and therefore its value can not be passed in.